# PHP file permissions for Development machine

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions, file-permissions

I've just upgraded my development machine and have moved over a website I was working on.  However, the permissions don't seem to have moved over properly.  The dev machine is a Linux machine which runs Apache, where all the folders and sub-folders were set to 755 and all the files and files within all sub folders were set to 644.

Instead of me having to run the commands:

`chmod 755 <folder name here>`

`chmod 644 <file name here>`

Is there a quicker way of doing this without having to do each and every file and folder individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chmod works recursively:

```
chmod xxx -R /path/
```

More info: http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod

Comment: He wants different flags on files and folders.

Comment: Do the entire thing in one pass, then go back and fix whichever you have the least of, files or folders, hah!

Answer (score 0):

Try `find . -type d | xargs chmod 755` and `find . -type f | xargs chmod 644`.